# how to check requested device info in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

I have to make mobile version of my website, i've made separate webforms for mobile, now i have to check whether a user has logged in from mobile or PC and on base of it i'll have to route on mobile or PC webforms

Can anyone suggest how can i check for logged in device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code gives an idea

```
string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
if (strUserAgent != null)
{
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") ||
strUserAgent.Contains("blackberry") || strUserAgent.Contains("mobile") ||
strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || strUserAgent.Contains("opera mini") ||
strUserAgent.Contains("palm"))
{
Response.Redirect("{desiredpage}.aspx");
}
}
```

Comment: i am getting mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1) applewebkit/537.17 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/24.0.1312.52 safari/537.17 in chrome, means this string will contains the name of device?

Comment: you are getting UserAgent / Browser engine info

Answer (score 0):

The device will pass you a UserAgent string in the HTTP Headers.

This string identifies the type of device trying to access your website. For example, the iPhone 5 will return

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3

Comment: i am getting mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1) applewebkit/537.17 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/24.0.1312.52 safari/537.17 in chrome, means this string will contains the name of device?