# How to fetch device name over the VPN in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vpn

I'm working on a project in which I've to fetch the device name of the user. For example, currently I'm using the desktop, so the device name is like DT******89789 which tells that the user is of desktop user. like wise I want to know the device name of the tablet and other devices also. This is the code which I've written in VB.Net to fetch the device name.

```
 Partial Class VB
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    
   Response.Write("Client Computer Name : " & System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName.ToString())

   End Sub
   End Class
```

The problem is when I run the above code, it's working fine in the local host(using visual studio 2015) as well as on the server(after uploading code on the server), It's fetching correct data but when I open the same website in the windows tablet over the VPN either the page throws error or doesn't show anything. It shows this error:-

### **\Server Error in '/' Application.

### The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /esp/vb.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.5**

I want the device name of the user like tablet in this case over the VPN. Thanks

Comment: Little out of my wheelhouse this one, so not sure exactly how valid but kind of feel you're going to want think about doing this via client side code.   Could be wrong here but would expect the Page_Load to execute server side, why it's working in debug is because the client and server are the same thing.

Comment: Maybe something like this is what you're after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357539/how-to-check-requested-device-info-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the answer I'm looking for, is not in the link that you've shared. I'm still looking for the solution of the problem on Google.